# Test for specific css property compatability programmatically (resize support on a textarea)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css, cross-browser

I'm implementing a resizeable textarea on a cross-browser website. Now in FF/Chrome/Safari, the following:

```
  textarea{
     resize: both;
  }
```

Works like a charm. A little bit of sniffing around has led me here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

Where I learned that Opera and IE do not support this property.

No biggie, the following javascript can take care of detection, with a jquery UI call to `resizable()` wrapped within for functionality:

```
 if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') != -1)){
```

However, I dislike explicit browser checks. Is there a way to test support for a specific css property programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of adeneo above, the final, general purpose solution is as follows:

```
 var shims_property_for_element, supports_property_on_element;

 shims_property_for_element = function(prop, elem, method, attrs) {
   if (!supports_property_on_element(prop, elem)) {
     return $(function() {
       var numEles;
       $(elem)[method](attrs);
       numEles = $(elem).length;
       return window.setInterval((function() {
         if ($(elem).length !== numEles) {
           numEles = $(elem).length;
           return $(elem)[method](attrs);
         }
       }), 1000);
     });
   }
 };

 supports_property_on_element = function(prop, elem) {
   var e, len, vendors;
   e = document.createElement(elem);
   if (prop in e.style) {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
 };
```

Which in this particular case then translates to the following call:

```
 shims_property_for_element('resize', 'textarea', "resizable")
```

Answer (score 5):

Check if a textarea's style declaration returns undefined for "resize", it if does, it's not supported:

```
var txtarea = document.createElement('textarea');

if (txtarea.style.resize != undefined) {
    //resize is supported
}
```

Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHSAA/1/) to test it. It returns OK in Chrome, and also in Opera, and i tested the CSS property "resize" in Opera, and it seems to work just fine, so it is supported in Opera. The test returns "no support" in IE, as expected.

Comment: @adeneo - Holy crap, look at all that great response you got from testing this in different browsers and figuring out how to check for a CSS property etc. It's just through the roof man ?????

Comment: It did, I went ahead and built out a more general purpose solution based on your input (see above)...

Thanks!

Comment: @AbrahamP - yeah, I figured a more general function that returns something would be a better option, and what you did there looks good. This is basically how you always test CSS properties, so I figured it should work for this is as well, but often times you just check the document, in this case a textarea is needed as the document never has this style, and will always return undefined.